# How to vectorise four lines of MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, range, vectorization, angle

Is it possible to rewrite the following MATLAB code into one single line by vectorization?

```
for ii=1:length(temp1)
    if temp1(ii)>=270; temp1(ii)=temp1(ii)-360;end
    if temp1(ii)<=-90; temp1(ii)=temp1(ii)+360;end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm under the impression you could go one step further

```
temp1 = temp1 + 360 * (temp1 >= 270) - 360 * (temp1 <= -90)
```

Answer (score 1):

A safer way would be to use [`mod`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html), because this is more robust and can handle correctly angles that are outside the range of `th < -450` or `th > 630`:

```
temp1 = mod(temp1,360); temp1(temp1 >= 270) = temp1(temp1 >= 270)-360;
```

You can also take inspiration from the function [`wrapTo180`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/wrapto180.html):

```
function lon = wrapTo180(lon)
%wrapTo180 Wrap angle in degrees to [-180 180]
%
%   lonWrapped = wrapTo180(LON) wraps angles in LON, in degrees, to the
%   interval [-180 180] such that 180 maps to 180 and -180 maps to -180.
%   (In general, odd, positive multiples of 180 map to 180 and odd,
%   negative multiples of 180 map to -180.)
%
%   See also wrapTo360, wrapTo2Pi, wrapToPi.

% Copyright 2007-2008 The MathWorks, Inc.

q = (lon < -180) | (180 < lon);
lon(q) = wrapTo360(lon(q) + 180) - 180;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just figured out myself after some minutes...

```
temp1(temp1>=270)=temp1(temp1>=270)-360;
temp1(temp1<=-90)=temp1(temp1<=-90)+360;
```